# Using coordinates to find distances between points and plotting them on a graph

Tags: geometry

Cleo lives the same distance from the library, the post office, and her school. The coordinates for each are listed below. The coordinates for the library are $(-78,202)$, the post office are $(111,193)$, and the school are $(202, -106)$. What are the coordinates of Cleo's home? Sketch the circle on  a map locating all three places and Cleo's home.

I have tried using the equation of a circle and setting them equal, but it doesn't seem to be helping with solving this question.

Comment: Equation of a circle is of the form $x^2 + y^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$. You can substitute the given points, you will get three equations. You can solve them for $g$, $f$ and $c$. The center of the circle will then be $(-g, -f)$. And that will be Cleo's home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equation of every circle is of the form $x^2 + y^2 +2gx + 2fy + c = 0$, where center of the cirlce is at $(-g, -f)$ and the radius is $\sqrt{g^2 + f^2 - c}$.

You have three points. You can substitute each of them one by one and you will get three equations:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
78^2 + 202^2 + 2(-78)g + 2(202)f + c = 0 \\
111^2 + 193^2 + 2(111)g +  2(193)f + c = 0 \\
202^2 + 106^2 + 2(202)g + 2(-106)f + c = 0 \\
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

When you solve them, you'll get $g = -7$ and $f = 2$.

Hence, the center of the circle is at $(7, -2)$.